# Are lamps connected in series on airports?

Tags: voltage, current

Long ago I learned about connecting things (e.g., lamps) in series and in parallel. A famous example of lamps connecting in series was at an airport, especially to indicate the landing strip. The purpose was to guarantee that all lamps would work together. If one lamp would be bad, all lamps would be off and no distorted signal would be visible.

Now I know that it is bad to connect incandescant lamps in series. Such lamps should be connected in parallel, or one lamp that would be just a little bit more worn out would get destroyed even faster because the series connection would result in a constant current supply, disastrous for lamps with a positive temperature coefficient, leading to thermal runaway.

Of course this is a historic question. Today, with LED lamps, the situation is exactly opposite. Leds must be connected in series and fed with a constant current. In parallel, one led with a v/i curve that is just slightly lower would be destroyed by the other leds.

With that knowledge, it is hard to believe that airport lamps (not led) were really connected in series. I googled on this and could not get answers. Does any one on this forum know about the application of lamps connected in series?

The only answer I do not appreciate is lamps for the christmas tree, because these were virtually always defective because of the reason stated above.

Comment: You should ask this on the Aviation Stack Exchange.

Comment: Where to begin.  The first three paragraphs have six statements of fact, and all six are incorrect.  For example, LED runway lights have a switching power supply circuit at each location, and those supplies powered in parallel.  Also, incandescent tree lights are connected in series because of cost.  And, they do not use "normal" bulbs; the bulbs have an internal bypass mechanism so one blown bulb does not kill an entire string.

Comment: Airport lamps commonly use series connection - see https://www.ecmweb.com/content/article/20888753/series-lighting-circuitry-why-use-it

Comment: @jsotola this site is named Electrical Engineering, not electronics design. And how to connect bulbs is indeed EE. The airport situation is even an advanced topic.

Comment: @KevinWhite Thanks for your very informative link. It could have made an interesting "answer". I'll gladly upvote both comments :-)

Comment: @DKNguyen Why? The very informative link is in an electrical engineering magazine. The only aviation aspect is that a pilot may request to dim the runway lighting, but how to easily dim that is again EE.

Comment: @DKNguyen I strongly suggest that you read my answer - or just skip to the cited reference. I didn't know any of this and it's very worth knowing.

Comment: @AnalogKid I strongly suggest that you read my answer - or just skip to the cited reference. I didn't know any of this and it's very worth knowing.

Comment: @jsotola I strongly suggest that you read my answer - or just skip to the cited reference. I didn't know any of this and it's very worth knowing.

Comment: @Roland I suggest that you take the "accept" off Harper's answer. It happens to be very wrong and the "accept" may mislead other people. Harper usually provides excellent answers and he may well modify this one - now that he and I know a lot more about airport lighting systems than we did yesterday ! :-). I suggest that you accept no answer for a day or two - Harper may well edit his answer so it reflects how these systems actually work.

Comment: @roland the aviation stack exchange doesnt just have pilots. on it. It is not pilot stack exchange. It has people involved in airport operations and maintenance. Pilots are a very small minority of the people involved in aviation.

Comment: An LED is certainly not destroyed by being connected in parallell, that's nonsense.

Comment: @MariusGulbrandsen Nonsense? You want to connect 2, or 5, or 50 LEDs to a 5V supply. I would use 50 resistors, one for each LED. You would say, nonsense, just connect all those LEDs in parallel and use just one resistor. Would work just fine, IF all leds are identical. And that's a big if. As soon as one led ages just a little different, or heats up just a little more than the others, the forward voltage will drop. But wait, it cannot drop because it is in parallel with the other 49 leds. So it needs a LOT of extra current to keep up the forward voltage. Thermal runaway. Dead very soon :-)

Comment: Harper's updated answer is now worth accepting.

Comment: Multiple LEDs in parallel with a single resistor feed are "bad news" but in many real world cases will last indefinitely without total destruction of any LED. The results depend greatly on LED balance (as you note) and on the number of LEDs. For large numbers of LEDs one with a lower Vf can more easily take substantially more current. I was involved with a factory producing LED based lights where in one instance that had replaced 6 x resistors, one per LED with a single common one. While this was definitely sub-optimum the results in practice were acceptable, ...

Comment: ... and much better than I would have expected.  ie the LEDs were visually mutually indistinguishable in operation, LED lifetimes without visible departure from OK were in excess of failure of the product overall for other reasons ('beaten to a pulp' in demanding developing country uses) ... . || I designed the next model of the product and used a boost converter and series LEDs with constant current feed.

Comment: @MariusGulbrandsen Nonsense? A much better narrative than mine about how a led connected in parallel, fed with a single constant current source, might destroy BOTH leds: [https://www.ledsmagazine.com/leds-ssl-design/driver-ics/article/16696028/led-design-forum-avoiding-thermal-runaway-when-driving-multiple-led-strings-magazine] (diagrams are hard to read but the text is very readable)

Comment: @Roland of course you would add resistors to the parallell connected LEDs. When speaking on a general basis and on the topic of LED lamps, the cost and size of a resistor is so small they are of course included. To say in general, as it was implied, that LEDs need to be connected in series is nonsense. While of course, in something like an airport strip with long distances, you would have a lot of voltage drop and may consider series connection a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question attracted a lot of good comments and two nice answers with lots of additional info and internet references. Also some silly discussions about what exactly is constant current, and what do lamps "need". This all made me read and think a lot. Here is my own answer based on all this info plus a new insight.

The part that has not been discussed yet is the `ferro-resonant transformer`. It was mentioned in the online articles for the supply of all those series connected lamps around the runway. Online there is a lot of info available, e.g., http://www.electroncoil.com/ferroresonant_transformers.php . The fun part is that the output voltage can be fairly constant, say within 1 %, even if the input voltage varies a lot, e.g. 10 %.

To supply power to a lot of small lamps spread over a large area (around the runway), a single wire is used to save the cost of a separate return wire. The voltage is high, 5 kV, so a relatively thin wire suffices. The extra cost of pvc for 5 kV rating is less than the saved cost on copper.

To insulate the lamp sockets from the high voltage, isolation transformers are needed at each lamp. The added advantage is that by choosing suitable winding ratios you can make all lamps appear, at the 5kV supply wire, to use the same current.

The term *constant current* is misleading. The input is the network voltage to the supply transformer at the control tower (or some other building), e.g. 110 V or 220 V, 380 V, or whatever, at 50/60 Hz. The voltage on the line to the runway is 5 kV. All series connected loads operate at 10V, 20V, whatever, and add up to that 5kV. The nominal current in that wire is 6.6 or 20 A.

So far nothing really special. Ordinary lamps rated at some voltage. Distributed lighting, as Harper-Reinstate Monica commented. The lamps are not really *series connected*, they just operate on their respective nominal voltages.

The special part is that all transformers are *ferro resonant*. The effect is that if one or several lamps blow out like every bulb does after some 1000 hours, the current on the 5kV side of that lamp's transformer keeps flowing, and that the total voltage of the entire string of loads stays about the same. The stabilizing working of the *ferro resonant transformer* is that if 10 percent of all lamps are dead, the current on the 5 kV only deviates 1 percent.

Notice also that this system is old. This could have been invented in, say, 1930, and this system may be common since, say, 1950. That we now have better power electronics and led lamps is not essential.

The answer, hence, is: Yes, lamps are connected in series on airports, BUT: the lamps are each still supplied by low-impedance *voltages* , provided by ferro-resonant isolation transformers.

Answer (score 9):

**EVERYONE** who is not aware of how series-fed constant current runway lighting systems work should read the excellent article cited by Kevin White.

- [Series Lighting Circuitry: Why Use It?](https://www.ecmweb.com/content/article/20888753/series-lighting-circuitry-why-use-it)

**Many airport lighting systems did and still do use series feed** - but, ...

- They are vastly more sophisticated systems than are used in eg Christmas Tree lights.

  - 10's of kW,
  - Up to 5 kV
  - Constant current AC feed,
  - Transformer coupled lights,
  - Immune to blown bulbs and various other faults.

**_____________________________**

> A famous example of lamps connecting in series was at an airport, especially to indicate the landing strip. The purpose was to guarantee that all lamps would work together. If one lamp would be bad, all lamps would be off and no distorted signal would be visible.

Airport lighting systems did and still do use series fed lighting systems. (Parallel lighting systems are also used). The system does NOT cause all lights to extinguish when one (or more) bulb fails - see below for technical details.

> ... it is hard to believe that airport lamps (not LED) were really connected in series.

But, this was and still is a common method of connection.
The reason it works is that equipment is provided at each light to transform the constant current AC feed into a standardised lamp supply voltage and to isolate the lamp if it fails.

A major feature of the systems is that in systems with 10's of kilowatts of lights spread over miles of circuit, they replace relatively low voltage high current feeds with much higher voltages and much lower currents - leading to "much much" lower wiring losses. eg a smallish sized [!] 30 kW system would require 220 A at 135V (!!!) but only 6A at 5 kV. As resistive losses are proportional to current squared, either losses can be (6/220)^2 = 0.07% as great for the same wiring size OR, more likely a wire size / power loss tradeoff can be implemented. eg using wire 4% the area of that used at 135V will result in 2% of the power losses.
(6A x 6A x 25R)/(220A x 220A x 1R) ~= 2% !!!

> The only answer I do not appreciate is lamps for the Christmas tree, because these were virtually always defective because of the reason stated above.

Christmas tree lights are a very very simple version of the same principle - and "better quality versions" had a bimetallic shorting mechanism that bypassed failed bubs so that a bulb failure did not extinguish the whole string.

A good outline is provided in the above article, but

- Airport series lighting systems operate at up to 5 kV feed voltages !
- Total lamp powers of up to 30 KW [!] uses a standard 6.6A constant current AC feed and
- Lamp powers over 30 kW use a 20A constant current AC feed.
- Use of up to 5 kV series connection allows typically "light weight" 8 gauge cables to be used :-)
- The constant current loop feeds transformer primaries, powering lamps at 6.6A and up to 135 V.
- Standard cable size for 6.6 A is 8 AWG (8 mm2) and for 20 A is 6 AWG (13 mm2)

They note that

- " ... Series lighting systems can operate for long periods under adverse conditions. In fact, they can operate with a large number of lamps burned out, with badly degraded cable systems, and even with shorts and grounds. ... "

and

- " ... Using 5kV cable as the standard will limit single circuit load blocks to a maximum of 90kW. But don't be concerned about this limitation, since ..." :-) .

The series transformer primaries is "interesting".
A bulb presents a load to the constant current system - no problem. An open circuit secondary (dead bulb) presents a high impedance primary choke.
They MAY use bulb shorters if bulb is blown to present low impedance primaries to current flow.

I did not know ANYTHING about these systems 2 hours ago !!!

**______________________________________**

**References:**

[An Introduction to Airport
Airfield Lighting](http://www.cscos.com/wp-content/uploads/Mechanical-6_Introduction-to-Airport-Lighting_Maxwell.pdf) - Powerpoint. 12 slides. Series and parallel systems

Lotsa links [Googlabet search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKmA-Hbc2bOndgz3T0rUdHo3eXKA:1575894067209&q=series+runway+lighting+system&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKktHwxqjmAhUs63MBHQXXCkIQsAR6BAgLEAE&biw=2457&bih=1269)

Historical - [Street Light Information Sheet - Understanding Series Circuits](http://www.kbrhorse.net/streetlights/understanding_series.html)

Note: This document is a continuation of [Understanding Early Street Light Circuits](http://www.kbrhorse.net/streetlights/understanding_circuits.html)

Comment: I was aware that runway lighting is series connected for one big plus not mentioned directly in your answer: series connection ensures the same brightness for all lamps in the circuit. This really matters in circuits that are thousands of meters long.

Comment: bulb shorters not needed. when secondary circuit is open, core will saturate and primary winding will be reduced to a small air coil with moderate impedance. good trick tough. Further: good summary of the article suggested by Kevin Whithe.

Comment: Series transformers is not really the same thing as series lighting, though.

Comment: @Transistor " ... same brightness ..." -> Sort of. By design yes. Of necessity, no. The circuits are constant current BUT not constant power per pickup point - and bulbs of differing wattages or clusters of bulbs can (o could) be operated per tapping point.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica " ... not the same ..."-> In this context I'd disagree. The bulbs are not physical-wiring series connected as are eg Christmas Tree Lights or series valve heater strings. But they are series connected energy flow wise. With CTL's the voltage drops about equally per bulb and energy packets are ;dropped off" per bulb. With series runway lights energy is equally 'dropped off' per station. CTLs are 'constant current' systems. But the constant is relatively unknown :-).

Comment: @Roland ... saturate ... -> Maybe if well designed. I'd be interested in knowing what they actually do. | I've seen similar issues in inductive loop power feed systems where an unloaded inductive 'tap' can cripple the system - and shorted secondaries are used to overcome this. (Or in some cases resonance modes may be changed to suit).

Comment: I see where it's a pretty metaphor, but each transformer secondary/lamp is a *separately derived service*.  Calling it series *lighting* is misleading, because that means something else, which implies a whole bunch of other problems.  Series-*distributed* lighting would feel better.  It's like when people say "rotary converter" when they mean "thing that lets them run 3-phase tools on single-phase", I cringe because something else has that name....

Comment: Good links! The powerpoint has a link to ADB, the link is dead, but I found the new site of ADB, and detailed info on the isolation transformer [https://adbsafegate.com/product-center/airfield/?prod=l-830-l-831-series-circuit-isolation-transformers]

Comment: I also mailed a question to ADB about saturation on open secondary. I will replace this comment by new info when it comes in

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The isolation transformers are not essential. The lamps could be connected in series without transformers. From a high level point of view the transformers are _transparent_ network devices, you could ignore those for lots of calculations. But in practice, the transformers are needed for lots of secondary reasons: isolation, and 'shunting' blown out bulbs. But jargon aside, my question was not about transformers, and I am glad I learned about those :-)

Comment: I'm super glad you enjoyed Russell's link.  However, I have added a lot of content to the top of my answer, and you also ought to give credence to that too.  I discuss at length why the transformers are vital to system reliability and dramatically change the dynamics.  The transformers are why the lamp string keeps working when a light goes out, instead of arcing with full string voltage.

Answer (score 0):

### Series incandescents *directly* are big trouble.

That would not work at all.  You'd need quite a high voltage to serve many lights over a long distance.  That high voltage would cause spectacularly destructive arcing when a bulb burns out! As the ~5000 volts arcs down the filament support wires, through the base and into the socket.  No trouble finding the burned out bulb; it's the one that's on fire!

### Airports use a transformer loop

What's in series is a string of transformers - one at each light location.  This solves the above problems.  It provides isolation from the high loop voltage; the transformer sits inside a high-voltage box the lamp replacement crew doesn't even have a key for.  The lamp socket voltages are sensible, and can be even isolated from earth.   If a lamp burns out, that has little effect on the transformer loop.

By varying the current in the transformer loop, they can brighten and dim all the runway lights together in equal measure - an important feature for runway lights.

By the way, city street lighting used to use the same trick.  If you heard about the obsolete series street lighting in Detroit that was unreliable, *that was this* -- the "unreliable" part was that the transformers sat at the bottom of the street light, and crooks kept stealing them for the copper.

### LEDs for runway lighting

Yes, reducing each lamp's voltage to 3 volts might tempt one to simply run a bunch of LED runway lights in series.  I think that is a bad idea.  First, carrying such low voltage long distances is *extremely* lossy and would require fat aluminum wires, not the #8 or #6 they use for airports.  Second, the transformer method now in use is proven, and easily adaptable for LED.

Remember, they are series transformers.  If you had an LED that took 1/10 the power, it would be easy to change the transformer to suit.  That particular transformer would take 1/10 the power, and since current is constant in a series loop, it would drop 1/10 the voltage.  You could *literally replace incandescents with LEDs one at a time* - the system loop voltage would drop slightly for each one.  Eventually you would probably go out-of-gamut for the supply equipment; it wouldn't be able to function at such a low voltage.  You could add a dummy load until the projet was complete, and then change to appropriate supply equipment.  *So no need to shut down the runway lighting; only one lamp goes out at a time*.

### Running  incandescents in series has serious issues

Not least, in a series lamp connection, the socket must be insulated for the highest system voltage. That makes changing lamps dangerous, and frankly, *even finding the bad lamp* is a bug hunt.

The stuff about incandescents needing parallel connection (constant-voltage mode) isn't true.   In fact, incandescents behave somewhat rudely when driven constant-voltage; they do *inrush current* which is also hard on lamp life.  Incandescents would behave better in constant-current. No inrush; they'd just warm up a smidge slower.

You may have heard about Edison's herculean "try everything" effort to find a viable filament.  A big part of the problem was finding a filament *that self-regulated* i.e. Was linear enough all by itself. Edison couldn't avail himself of a constant-current *transformer*, because of needing to make this work on DC power - using a ballast would have conceded the war to Tesla!

Meanwhile, Tesla had just presumed any lamp would need to be driven in constant-current mode, and out of that Tesla developed sealed arc-discharge lighting such as neon and fluorescent.  That stuff is non-ohmic and acts like a dead short, so you have to ballast it.  Easy to do with AC power!

So wiring an incandescent in series would be perfectly reasonable if you were driving the string constant-current.  Of course, **the bulb needs to be able to snuff the arc** which lights when the bulb burns out, and transformer max voltage is trying to leap across the dead bulb.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102060/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-reinstate-monica-are-lamps-connected-in-series). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).