# Airport runway lighting: What is constant current in relation to alternating and direct current?

Tags: ac, dc, high-voltage, constant-current, lighting

I’m an *apprentice* electrician currently replacing runway lights and pulling new wire at a small international airport.

When I asked I was told they are 5kV **direct current**. Okay… simple enough. What piqued my interest was the label on the lights- they are rated for 50/60 Hz and use a small step down transformer for each light. DC circuit using transformers at 60 Hz? Wait a second. Through some light reading (I’m not that smart) I understand these runway lighting circuits utilize constant current regulators.

The Wikipedia article on constant current defines it as a *type* of direct current. Is this really the case or is that just a simplified way of looking at it?

I understand the need for **constant current** when powering lights over long distances but I do not understand what it is in relation to alternating and direct current.

What would this current look like on an oscilloscope? Is it a flat line like DC or does it have a sinusoidal waveform like AC?

Is there any kind of rectification going on in the regulator or is it something completely different?

Comment: Do you have the manufacturers part number for the runway lights? Looking up the datasheet for the lights could give more information. Perhaps there is an AC -> DC power supply inside the lights which then applies a constant DC current to the actual light.

Comment: There is probably a conversion circuit inside the light itself, running 5kVDC all over the place sounds like a total nightmare, but @ChesterGillon said it: the datasheet tells all.

Comment: I’ve never encountered an airport light system which uses anything but AC. Most of them in constant current configuration.

Comment: @Chester Gillon I did not try looking up the light! I will get the number tomorrow and see what I can find, I’ll post it here too for anyone curious. Looking at suppliers websites I do believe the entire circuit is constant current which is provided by a large cabinet style regulator, not inside the light… but I am only going off my limited knowledge and research.

Comment: @winny Thank you for adding! It sounds like I’m being fed misinformation from my coworkers. Someone even told me they had a non contact voltage tester or proximity detector go off on one of these circuits which means it HAS to be AC.

Comment: @IncompetentJim Some NCV detectors can sense high DC voltages too, by measuring the electric field.

Comment: Have a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470908/are-lamps-connected-in-series-on-airports

Comment: You can turn AC or DC into a constant current, it doesn't matter where the power comes from; conversion is trivial these days.

Comment: @D Duck Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for. I can verify these circuits are entirely AC from the input to the output at 5kV and the lights themselves. Now I want to track down the person that started this whole conspiracy of direct current taxiway lighting, maybe I’m being pedantic but I think it’s dangerous, potentially lethal, to not know what kind of system you’re working on.

Comment: @dandavis That answered my original question, it’s a circuit configuration that could be an AC or DC system and not a “type of current”. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time we deal with constant voltage supplies, for example you might have a 12 V supply, and the current in the circuit will depend on the resistance as described by Ohm’s Law I = V/R. So for a 12 \$\Omega\$ load the current will be 1 A. If the load changes to 6 \$\Omega\$ the current will be 2 A so the voltage eill still be 12 V.

For constant current the current stays constant and the voltage changes to satisfy Ohm’s Law. A 1 A CCS will output 12 V into a 12 \$\Omega\$ load, if the load changes to 6 \$\Omega\$ the voltage will be 6 V so the current will still be 1 A.

Imagine putting two 120 V lamps in series, with 120 V they would be dim, to get the normal brightness you would need to double the voltage to 240 V. With three in series you would need 360 V. A CCS does this automatically.

The idea of constant current is that you can have long wire runs without the problem of voltage drop, it adjusts the voltage to compensate for any additional resistance.

Comment: One big reason to use constant current in lighting is for compensating for the (negative) change in forward voltage with temperature of LED diodes. With CC you turn on a large light at a higher voltage and then as it warms up the driver slowly drops the voltage as the diode forward voltages decrease. Keeps the lights from entering into thermal runaway.

Comment: @GodJihyo Thank you for the in depth explanation! I still have some sleuthing to do as the guys I work with are convinced it’s a DC circuit but evidence is pointing to the opposite.